# OpenSSL BIGNUM BN_mod_exp problems

Tags: cryptography, openssl, bignum

I am having some issues coming up with "the correct answer" using OpenSSL's BIGNUM library.  I am using OpenSSL 1.0.1c (May 2012, latest package available in the standard Mint repos).

I am using BIGNUMs for a cryptography project that uses finite fields (aka Galois fields).  Basically i have a large prime (q) and a safe prime (p, where p = 2q + 1).  My field is Fp of order q.

I need to generate a "g".  The easiest way i've found to do this is to pick a random "h" (1 < h < p-1), then do g = h^((p-1)/q) mod p.  With the "g" i get out of that, i should be able to prove that it is in the FF by doing g^q mod p = 1.

When I do this for any reasonable small numbers on paper it holds true.  However, when I do it using OpenSSL and big, prime numbers, it doesn't work!  When I test whether my result of g^q mod p == 1, it constantly fails using BN_is_one().  If I print out the value, it's always a large unrelated prime.

What is going on?  I'm not sure what's going on here, or if I'm misunderstanding something.

Snippets of my code below:

```c
BN_generate_prime(q, KEYSIZE - 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); //generate "q"

// Calculate "p" = 2q + 1 
BN_lshift1(p, q);
BN_add(p, p, one);  //one = BN_one()

// 1: gExp = (p-1)/q
// 2: h =>   1 < h < (p-1)
// 3: g = h^gExp mod p
BN_div(gExp, NULL, pMinusOne, q, ctx);      // (1)
BN_pseudo_rand_range(h, pMinusOne);         // (2)
BN_mod_exp(g, h, gExp, p, ctx);             // (3)

BN_mod_exp(temp, g, q, p, ctx); // g^q mod p = 1, or it should
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are computing it in your snippet, `p` is not necessarily prime, it's just a number that is of the form `2*q+1` with `q` prime. For many small values of `q`, this `p` happens to be prime, but that is mostly coincidence and if you checked with `BN_is_prime`  you will likely find the `p`s you are generating do not pass the tests.

Instead, generate `p` directly by setting the `safe` parameter of `BN_generate_prime` and then compute `q` by a right shift, as with `safe` the prime will be of the form you need, and chopping off the lowest bit gives you a prime `q`.

Comment: Oh man, you're completely right.  I didn't even think about that!  It looks like i need to do some reading about "Safe" primes (and bonus for the `safe` parameter of BN_generate_prime.  Thanks!